# Optimization over a conic

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, continuity

Find global maximum and global minimum of

$$f(x,y) = \frac{\ln \left(\frac54y^2+(x-2)^2 \right)}{\sqrt[3]y}$$

over

$$D = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :\frac14 y^2 + (x-2)^2 = 1 \right\}$$

My textbook says the minimum is at $(2;-2)$ and the maximum at $(2;2)$, but I don't know how to prove it. I tried to draw level curves with no success .Then I tried with Lagrange multipliers test and it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I've just corrected it.

Comment: I do not claim tha it is easy, I claim that it is classic and you need to check your calculations. Sorry, but to solve such problems is a matter of concetration, that I do not say it is easy, but it is classic...take a look agin in your notes, about the way that you handle such problems...

Answer (score 0):

Let $\bar{x} := x-2$ and $\bar{y} := 0.5y$. Then, the objective function and feasible region of your transformed problem are $f(\bar{x},\bar{y}) := \frac{\text{ln}(5\bar{y}^2 + \bar{x}^2)}{\sqrt[3]{2\bar{y}}}$ and $\bar{D} := \left\{ (\bar{x},\bar{y}) \: : \: \bar{x}^2 + \bar{y}^2 = 1\right\}$.

Next, use the transformation $\bar{y} := \sin(\theta)$ and $\bar{x} := \cos(\theta)$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. The objective function is transformed to $f(\theta) = \frac{\text{ln}(1 + 4\sin^2(\theta))}{\sqrt[3]{2\sin(\theta)}}$, and the constraint is $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.

Finally, use the transformation $z := \sqrt[3]{\sin(\theta)}$. The constraint now is $z \in [-1,1]$ and the objective function is $f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}} \frac{\text{ln}(1 + 4z^6)}{z}$. I will [let you prove that $f$ is a monotonically increasing function of $z$ on this interval](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+ln%281%2B4z%5E6%29%2Fz%2C+z+in+%5B-1%2C1%5D), which implies that the minimum is attained at $z = -1$ and the maximum is attained at $z = +1$.

Backtracking, we get that the minimum is attained at $(x,y) = (2,-2)$ and the maximum is attained at $(x,y) = (2,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

With Lagrange multipliers.

$$
L = \frac{\ln \left(\frac54y^2+(x-2)^2 \right)}{\sqrt[3]y}+\lambda \left(\frac14 y^2 + (x-2)^2 - 1\right)
$$

The stationary points are determined by the solutions to

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 2 (x-2) \left(\lambda  \sqrt[3]{y} \left(4 (x-2)^2+5 y^2\right)+4\right) \\
 3 y^2 \left(\lambda  \sqrt[3]{y} \left(4 (x-2)^2+5 y^2\right)+20\right)-2 \left(4 (x-2)^2+5 y^2\right) \ln \left((x-2)^2+\frac{5 y^2}{4}\right) \\
 y^2+4 (x-4) x+12 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Analyzing those equations we can observe that $x=2$ gives

$$
0=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 0 \\
 3 y^2 \left(5 \lambda  y^{7/3}+20\right)-10 y^2 \log \left(\frac{5 y^2}{4}\right) \\
 y^2-4 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

now with $y = 2$ we have

$$
0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 0 \\
 12 \left(20 \sqrt[3]{2} \lambda +20\right)-40 \log (5) \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{\log (5)-6}{6 \sqrt[3]{2}}
$$

and for $y = -2$ we have

$$
0=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 0 \\
 12 \left(-20 \sqrt[3]{2} \lambda +20\right)-40 \log (5) \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\Rightarrow \lambda = -\frac{\log (5)-6}{6 \sqrt[3]{2}}
$$

thus obtaining as stationary points $(2,\pm 2)$

NOTE

To consider the solutions with the branch obtained from $ \left(\lambda  \sqrt[3]{y} \left(4 (x-2)^2+5 y^2\right)+4\right)=0$ we proceed as follows: considering $z = 4 (x-2)^2+5 y^2$ we have

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \lambda  \sqrt[3]{y} z+4 & = &0\\
 3 y^2 \left(\lambda  \sqrt[3]{y} z+20\right)-2 z \log \left(\frac{z}{4}\right) & = & 0\\
 4 y^2-z+4 & = & 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Solving for $y,z,\lambda$ we obtain $z = 1589.53, y = \pm 19.9094$ and now solving

$$
\cases{5y^2+4(x-2)^2=  1589.53\\
y =\pm 19.9094
}
$$

we obtain in any case, complex values for $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think you should also consider the other possible solution of the first equation - even though it has no real solutions but you can't be sure about that.

Comment: Considering the branch corresponding to $\lambda  \sqrt[3]{y} \left(4 (x-2)^2+5 y^2\right)+4=0$ we obtain all complex solutions.

Comment: @zinne98 Please. See attached note.