# Rewrite as conic optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-cone

Can I rewrite the convex optimization problem

\begin{align}
&\min \,\, f(x_1,x_2) \\
&\text{s.t.} \, \, x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq r
\end{align}

with $r \in \mathbb{R}$ as a conic optimization problem? As far as I know, the set described by the constraint is not a cone, since for example it is not closed w.r.t. addition or a scalar multiplication. However, I found the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612478/optimization-over-a-conic) where a problem with a similar quadratic equality constraint is described as conic. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a problem to be conic, you do not require $x$ itself to be in a cone, but rather $Ax+b\in K$, where $K$ is a cone. The constraint in your case is

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}x + \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ \sqrt{r}\end{pmatrix} \in K$$
where $K$ is the second order cone.

Whether the problem is conic depends on the objective function.

Comment: Thanks! What are the restrictions for the objective function? The domain has to be a cone?

I cannot completly get how the second order cone should be in order to describe the constraint in the original problem. Can you give the equation or a reference? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Trb2 The objective should also be conic representable. In other words, is $f(x_1,x_2) \leq y$ conic. There is only one second order cone, see for example Example 2 in [these notes](https://people.orie.cornell.edu/dpw/orie6300/Lectures/lec26.pdf).